# SWIG Converting a vector of vectors to a list of lists for Python, 'x' was not declared in this scope

Tags: python, c++, wrapper, swig

I have a short c++ function that populates a vector of vectors when given inputs a,b which are rows and columns, like this
vec_of_vec.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "vec_of_vec.h"
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::vector<int>> f(int a, int b) {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> mat;

    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        // construct a vector of int
        std::vector<int> v;
        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++) {
            v.push_back(j+i);
        }

        // push back above one-dimensional vector
        mat.push_back(v);
    }
return mat;
}
```

its header file
vec_of_vec.h

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED
#define FUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED

#include <vector>
#include <functional>
std::vector<std::vector<int>> f(int a,int b); 

#endif
```

From here I want to call this code from python so I try and wrap it with SWIG. This is the interface file I've been using. I've taken inspiration from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58405205/typemap-resources-and-converting-a-list-to-vector-and-back) post.

vec_of_vec.i

```
%module vec_of_vec
#define SWIGPYTHON_BUILTIN
%{
#include "vec_of_vec.h"
#include <vector>
%}

%include <std_vector.i>
%template(VectorOfInt) std::vector<int>;
%template(VectorOfStructVector) std::vector<std::vector<int> >;


%typemap(out) std::vector<std::vector<int>> (PyObject* _inner,PyObject* _outer) %{
    // Allocate a PyList object of the requested size.
    _outer = PyList_New($1.size());
    // Populate the PyList.  PyLong_FromLong converts a C++ "long" to a
    // Python PyLong object.
    for(int x = 0; x < $1.size(); x++)
        _inner = PyList_New($1[x].size());
        for(int y = 0; y < $1[x].size(); y++)
            PyList_SetItem(_inner,y,PyLong_FromLong($1[x][y]));
        PyList_SetItem(_outer,x,_inner);
   $result = SWIG_Python_AppendOutput($result,_outer);
%}

%include "vec_of_vec.h"
```

This is the makefile:

```
all:
        rm -f *.so *.o *_wrap.* *.pyc *.gch vec_of_vec.py
        swig -c++ -python vec_of_vec.i
        g++ -fpic -c vec_of_vec_wrap.cxx vec_of_vec.h vec_of_vec.cpp -I/usr/include/python3.8
        g++ -shared vec_of_vec_wrap.o vec_of_vec.o -o _vec_of_vec.so
```

When I call this I get an error:

```
vec_of_vec_wrap.cxx: In function ‘PyObject* _wrap_f(PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
vec_of_vec_wrap.cxx:9412:3: error: expected initializer before ‘for’
 9412 |   for(x = 0; x < (&result)->size(); x++)
      |   ^~~
vec_of_vec_wrap.cxx:9412:40: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
 9412 |   for(x = 0; x < (&result)->size(); x++)
      |                                        ^
      |                                        ;
vec_of_vec_wrap.cxx:9414:7: error: ‘y’ was not declared in this scope
 9414 |   for(y = 0; y < result[x].size(); y++)
      |       ^
make: *** [makefile:4: all] Error 1
```

However when I try and populate it manually, in the interface file, without a for loop, something similar to this:

```
%typemap(out) std::vector<std::vector<int>> (PyObject* _inner,PyObject* _outer) %{
    // Allocate a PyList object of the requested size.
    _outer = PyList_New($1.size());
    _inner = PyList_New($1[0].size());
    PyList_SetItem(_inner,0,PyLong_FromLong($1[0][0]));
    PyList_SetItem(_inner,1,PyLong_FromLong($1[0][1]));
    PyList_SetItem(_outer,0,_inner);
    ...
    $result = SWIG_Python_AppendOutput($result,_outer);
%}
```

it returns a list of lists.

Another thing is that if i change %typemap(out) to %typemap(argout), I get a tuple of tuples back, but it works without errors.

If it's not obvious, I'm not very proficient with c++ or swig but I'm trying to find my way around it but can't figure it out for the life of me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, although the error message doesn't agree with the code shown or the error in the title.  Code shown is `for(int x = 0...)` but error message is `for(x = 0...)`.  In the code shown you are missing the marked curly braces below in the `%typemap(out)` implementation:

```cpp
%typemap(out) std::vector<std::vector<int>> (PyObject* _inner,PyObject* _outer) %{
    // Allocate a PyList object of the requested size.
    _outer = PyList_New($1.size());
    // Populate the PyList.  PyLong_FromLong converts a C++ "long" to a
    // Python PyLong object.
    for(int x = 0; x < $1.size(); x++) {  // <<<<<<< MISSING
        _inner = PyList_New($1[x].size());
        for(int y = 0; y < $1[x].size(); y++)
            PyList_SetItem(_inner,y,PyLong_FromLong($1[x][y]));
        PyList_SetItem(_outer,x,_inner);
    } // <<<<<<< MISSING
   $result = SWIG_Python_AppendOutput($result,_outer);
%}
```

Output after fix:

```py
>>> import vec_of_vec as vv
>>> vv.f(3,5)
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

Note that your code worked with `%typemap(argout)` because there is a default `%typemap(out)` for the `vector<vector<int>>` template you declared that generates a tuple of tuples, and `%typemap(argout)` simply wasn't used.  If a tuple of tuples is OK for you, then you don't need the `%typemap(out)` that outputs a list of lists.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was it! And thanks for the additional explanation of argout too